# The problem about Google Play's target API level requirement

Tags: android

From the article https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk,

Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

The following code is from my app.

1:  Does it mean that targetSdkVersion must be greater than or equal to 26 ?

2:  Does it mean that minSdkVersion can be  21 ?

**Code**

```
defaultConfig {

        applicationId "info.dodata.mirror"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 9
        versionName "1.09"
        archivesBaseName = "My-V" + versionName
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1: Does it mean that targetSdkVersion must be greater than or equal to
>   26 ?

Yes.

> 2: Does it mean that minSdkVersion can be 21 ?

Yes. (or any lower version you need to support)

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element):

> **android:minSdkVersion**
>
> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the
>   application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from
>   installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the
>   value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this
>   attribute.
>
> **android:targetSdkVersion**
>
> An integer designating the API Level that the application targets. If
>   not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. This
>   attribute informs the system that you have tested against the target
>   version and the system should not enable any compatibility behaviors
>   to maintain your app's forward-compatibility with the target version.
>   The application is still able to run on older versions (down to
>   minSdkVersion).