# Google Play Console Target SDK Level 26 requirement

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Understand Google Play has a new API requirement:

> Google Play will require that new apps target at least Android 8.0
>   (API level 26) from August 1, 2018, and that app updates target
>   Android 8.0 from November 1, 2018.

Previously I uploaded an APK that was has the following values:
[image]

Afterwards I made an updated **before November 2018**:

[image]

I plan to do an update soon and would like to ensure I am meeting all requirements beforehand.

Does it mean I have fulfilled the new API requirement? Should I be looking at API levels or Target SDK? Is API levels referring to the minimum API level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check your android manifest for the following lines:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

As long as the target is 26 and above, I believe it should work fine.

I have published an apk recently using this without any issues.

You may refer to: [The problem about Google Play's target API level requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233892/the-problem-about-google-plays-target-api-level-requirement?rq=1) , in which someone has explained the min and target version.